# sum of independent rows of a data frame in an escalating way

Tags: r, matrix

I have a `data.frame` that is 100x100 and I need to sum them up as an escalator. Starting with the first entry of the first column and then keep adding the first entry of the second column to the second entry of the first and so on until the the last entry to sum is the last row of the last column. Looking at it as a diagonal matrix such as

```
d3 <- data.frame(a = c(rep(0.5,5),0,0), b = c(0,rep(0.3,5),0), e = c(0,0,rep(0.8,5)))
```

might be helpful to understand the problem. I want to sum the rows of a matrix like `d3`.

I tried to create a small example but I haven't been able to create a cycle or a function that simplifies the job.

I have this data:

```
d <- data.frame(a = rep(0.5,5), b = rep(0.3,5), e = rep(0.8,5))
```

and I need a way to create a single vector with the entries:

```
d2 <- rep(NA)
d2[1] <- d$a[1]
d2[2] <- sum(d$a[2],d$b[1])
d2[3] <- sum(d$a[3],d$b[2],d$e[1])
d2[4] <- sum(d$a[4],d$b[3],d$e[2])
d2[5] <- sum(d$a[5],d$b[4],d$e[3])
d2[6] <- sum(d$b[5],d$e[4])
d2[7] <- d$e[5]
```

that is equal to `c(0.5, 0.8, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.1, 0.8)`.

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Best to use matrices, not data.frames. You can identify your "escalator" selection of rows, `esca`, with a 0/1 matrix to multiply against `d`, like `d%*%esca`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
 rowSums(
    mapply(function(x,y) {
       ret<-numeric(nrow(d)+ncol(d)-1)
       ret[y:(y+length(x)-1)]<-x
       ret},d,1:(length(d)))
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
m1 <- as.matrix(d)
unname(tapply(m1, col(m1)+row(m1), FUN=sum))
#[1] 0.5 0.8 1.6 1.6 1.6 1.1 0.8
```